# Raspberry Pi 3 B+ microphone and speaker sound setup not working

Tags: audio, microphone

Trying to have the speakers on the 3.5m plug on the board, and use the USB Card for the microphone.

Don't know if that's even possible.

Current values:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****

card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 0: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA]
  Subdevices: 7/7
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6

card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 1: bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI [bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Device [USB PnP Sound Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]

  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

    pi@raspberrypi:~ $ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 1: Device [USB PnP Sound Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

.asoundrc file:

pcm.!default {
        type hw
        slave {
                pcm "hw:0,0"
        }
}

ctl.!default {
        type hw
        card 0
}


pcm.!default {
        type hw
        card 0
}

ctl.!default {
        type hw
        card 0
}

Some lines from alsa.conf

#
defaults.ctl.card 1
defaults.pcm.card 1
defaults.pcm.device 0
defaults.pcm.subdevice -1
defaults.pcm.nonblock 1
defaults.pcm.compat 0
defaults.pcm.minperiodtime 5000         # in us
defaults.pcm.ipc_key 5678293
defaults.pcm.ipc_gid audio
```

Have tried a LOT of different settings...looked at a LOT of posts. Most of 'em are old though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes i had a similar problem and was able to solve it using these steps.

1. check your speakers device no and card no.

   ```
   aplay -l
   ```
2. check your microphones device no and card no.

   ```
   arecord -l
   ```
3. Set your microphone and speaker as the Default PCM Devices

   ```
   sudo nano .asoundrc
   ```
4. Copy the below code and replace mic and speakers device and card no.

   ```
   pcm.!default {
     type asym
     capture.pcm "mic"
     playback.pcm "speaker"
   }
   pcm.mic {
     type plug
     slave {
       pcm "hw:<card number>,<device number>"
     }
   }
   pcm.speaker {
     type plug
     slave {
       pcm "hw:<card number>,<device number>"
     }
   }
   ```
5. check your microphone

   ```
   arecord --format=S16_LE --duration=5 --rate=16000 --file-type=raw out.raw
   ```
6. Check your speaker

   ```
   aplay --format=S16_LE --rate=16000 out.raw
   ```
7. Volume controls

   ```
   alsamixer
   ```

Comment: Thank you!

However, I got a better USB Dongle and that works very well:

https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B06XBZ38ZJ/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o04_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

z

Comment: Also planning on getting a Raspberry 4 .....maybe that solves a lot of problems with 3.....